# Passing 2D array inside struct to another struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to code a tricky thing in C/C++. I have an 2D array pointer inside a structure, and I would like to pass the address of the i-th (in the example bellow the 3th) row of the 2D array as a pointer to another struct.

Here is the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int t1[5][10];
} TEST1;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int * t2;
}TEST2;

TEST1 a;
TEST2 b;


unsigned int test2(unsigned int * data)
{
    int i,j,k;
    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            a.t1[i][j]=k;
            cout << a.t1[i][j] << " ";
            k++;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    data = &(a.t1[3][0]);
    cout << *data << endl;

    return 10;
}

void test()
{
    unsigned int size,i;

    size = test2(b.t2);

    cout << (b.t2) << endl;

}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the code is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
30
0
```

Why printing "data" inside gives me the right answer and printing "b.t2" gives me 0? It seems that "data" is not being passed as reference to "b.t2"

Comment: Instead of this data = &(a.t1[3][0]); you can use like *data =(a.t1[3][0]); means you will get correct output.

Comment: If `data` is modified as a seperate instance how do you expect `b.t2` which is not pointing to any valid location to hold this changed value?

Comment: Cool, guys I figured that out. Thanks for the answers. Actually I should make test2() return the address then, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, inside `test2()` function

`data = &(a.t1[3][0]);`

you're trying to alter the *address* held by data and expecting to refect that change in `test()`. You cannot do that. You can change the value at the address held by `data`, not the `data` itself from `test2()`.

In `test()`, `data` will still be uninitalized.

Remember, c uses pass-by-value. `data` itself has been passed by value.

If you have to alter `data` itself, you need to pass a pointer to `data` to `test2()`.

As a note, `*data` is equivalent to `*(b.t2)`

Comment: I didn't downvote, actually it was a good answer. :) Thanks for the answer. Then actually I have to make test2() return the address and take it in test() is that right?

Comment: @DiegoTsutsumi absolutely. that's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing the value of `b.t2` to `test2`. The value of `b.t2` itself **will not** change. It is still NULL when you call `cout << (b.t2) << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't even printing the same things. In the function you print the integer the data is pointing to: `*data`, and outside the function you are printing the value of a pointer `b.t2`

If you want the pointer to change outside the function pass the address of the pointer:

```
unsigned int test2(unsigned int** data)
{
    ...
   *data = &(a.t1[3][0]);
```

If you now print the value of `b.t2` it won't be NULL anymore.

```
size = test2(&b.t2);

cout << (b.t2) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` as it is is a separate pointer for which you are passing some unintialized value which is `b.t2`.

So the changes in data are not reflected in `b.t2`. Else you should have data as a double pointer to hold the address of your single pointer b.t2 and pass this value by reference to make sure the changes to data results in changes to `b.t2` also.

or

```
b.t2 = test2();

unsigned int *test2()
{
// GO ahead and make `data` point to some valid memory location and return that location
}
```

C code for this:

```
struct node
{
    int *p;
};

int *test2()
{
    int *t = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *t =10;
    return t;
}
int main(void) {
    struct node n;
    n.p = test2();
    printf("%d",*(n.p));
    return 0;
}
```